# SQL Delete sentence in one string that exists in another

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, mailing

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2016.

I have two strings containing email addresses called `@Recipients` and `@Copy_Recipients`.

I need to `cut out` those emails from `@Copy_Recipients` that exists in `@Recipients`.

```
@Recipients = 'john_snow@com.eu;daenerys_stormborn@com.eu;tonny_hawk@com.eu';

@Copy_Recipients = 'john_snow@com.eu;daenerys_stormborn@com.eu;tommy_leejones@com.eu;johny_cash@com.eu;';

@Wanted_Result = 'tommy_leejones@com.eu;johny_cash@com.eu;';
```

I know I am not bringing any idea of how to fix this. That's why I am writing. To ask what methods or functions could I use to achieve my goal. Thank you.

Comment: You need to tag the exact RDBMS (e.g. SQL Server, MySQL, Postgres) you're using because each could have its own approach to the problem.

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: Hint : [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) `@Copy_Recipients`, check for Not [EXISTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) in `@Recipients`, [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) the result to form new `@Copy_Recipients `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on SQL Server 2017 or later, you can use [`STRING_SPLIT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and [`STRING_AGG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(copy.value, ';')
  FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Copy_Recipients, ';') copy
  LEFT OUTER
  JOIN STRING_SPLIT(@Recipients, ';') recipients
    ON recipients.value = copy.value
 WHERE recipients.value IS NULL
```

[Working demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f78437fe115ce4ca5f6c459622ee28ac)

If you're on earlier versions of SQL Server, you'll have to use workarounds for the functions used above.

If you're on 2016, you can do it slightly differently:

```
DECLARE @Result NVARCHAR(MAX) = @Copy_Recipients

SELECT @Result = REPLACE(@Result, value, '') FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Recipients, ';')
```

And the final result with semicolons trimmed:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(@Result, PATINDEX('%[^;]%', @Result), LEN(@Result)) AS FinalResult
```

Comment: unfortunately I am using SQL Server 2016. ```STRING_AGG``` isn't available for me. What would you suggest instead?

Comment: I updated my answer with a way to do it in 2016, you'll have to deal with left-over ; at the beginning/end of the recipient list, should be easy enough.

Comment: Actually it's as easy as TRIM(';' FROM @Result), updated again.

Comment: ```Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'``` I tried declaring @Result before but it seem to have problem with this.

Comment: Oh my, `TRIM( ... FROM ...) ` is also only 2019! I updated the answer with a solution that will work on 2016 as per the demo fiddle.

Comment: @Simonsoft177, as an FYI, using the syntax `SELECT @Variable = @Variable + ... FROM` is a [documented antipattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/select-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#c-antipattern-use-of-recursive-variable-assignment) and should be avoided. Instead use string aggregation to achieve the same results. In recent versions of SQL Server that would be by using `STRING_AGG`, however, in older versions you'll need to use `FOR XML PATH` (and `STUFF`) to achieve the same results.